# Intelijj Idea move Junit tests to new class while refactoring

Tags: intellij-idea, junit

I have a class `A` with code and class `ATest` with tests: `testcase1`, `testcase2`... . I added new code to `A` and new `testcaseN` to `ATest`. During refactoring, I observed that class `A` is to big and could be split into two separate classes: `A` and `B`. Some test cases should be moved from `ATest` to newly created `BTest`.

Is there any method to do this automatically in Intellij to move selected methods and change access to remaining `ATest` class properties and help methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can place the cursor on the method name, that you wish to move. Then select `Refactor` -> `Move instance method...`. There will be a wizard on what to do next for related instances, helper methods...

Comment: It doesn't solve this problem. When I want to move `testcaseN` (which use both `A` and `B` class) to `BTest` in a wizard there is only possibility to move it to `A` or `B` class (not `BTest`)